# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting, I have this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to generate a query to remove data from my database, but I get the following error: `TypeError: not all arguments have been converted during string formatting`. Where am I going wrong?

```py
def delete(name):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres", user="postgres",
                            password="password", host="localhost", port="5432")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = '''DELETE FROM products WHERE name IN {%s} '''
    cursor.execute(query, [name])
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of `{}` and `%s` are formatting placeholders in `psycopg2`, see [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Using them both at once means no sense. You can fix it by replacing this:

```py
query = '''DELETE FROM products WHERE name IN {%s} '''
```

with this:

```py
query = '''DELETE FROM products WHERE name IN %s '''
```

Also, I'm not sure if it changes anything, but the second argument for `cursor.execute` has to be a tuple, not a list. Consider replacing `cursor.execute(query, [name])` with `cursor.execute(query, (name,))`.

Comment: thank you very much that solved the problem, your help has been very useful to me

Comment: @DiegoVillalba glad to help. If my answer helped you consider marking it as right.